# onMethod() in Scala (observer pattern)

Tags: c#, scala

An elementary thing has slipped my mind. Let's say, I have an object or a class in Scala:

```
object MyClass {
  def start(a: Int) = { ... }
}
```

When `start` method is called, I want to do some actions **whenever** it's called. I wonder, is it the Scala-way to add `onStart` function?

```
object MyClass {
  def start(a: Int) = { 
    //....doing something
    onStart(a)
  }
}
```

In C# I'd use an `event`.  But here I either completely forgot what to do or there is no such capacity in Scala itself and what I can do is use the observer pattern.

How do I "subscribe" to `onStart(a)` (if I have to)? If not, what should I use? I could add an additional parameter (function-callback) to `start`, though.

Comment: You can use [`Publisher`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.Publisher) and [`Subscriber`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.Subscriber) to create (unsuprisingly) a publisher-subscriber scenario. Or use `Scala.React`, same as you would use `Reactive Extensions`.

Comment: Another Reactive-Extensions-like library for Scala is RxJava (https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava) which has a Scala adapter.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I'd like a simplest solution possible

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek I'd like a simplest solution possible, no third-party libraries.

Comment: @Alex Then you can use `Publisher` and `Subscriber` just fine, they're built in - `scala.collection.mutable` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Publisher
import scala.collection.mutable.Subscriber

abstract class Event
case class OnStart(a : Int) extends Event


object MyClass extends Publisher[Event] {
  def start(a: Int) = {
    // do something handy   
    publish(OnStart(a))
  }
}

object Client extends App with Subscriber[Event, Publisher[Event]] {
    MyClass.subscribe(this)   
    MyClass.start(10)

    override def notify(pub: Publisher[Event], event: Event) : Unit = {     
        event match {
          case OnStart(a) => print("OnStart event")
        }
    }   
}
```